# Is there a function for finding the first member in an array which greater then a threshold

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cumsum

I need to find the index of the first member in an array where the cumulative sum until that point is bigger then a specific threshold, the code I got is this:

```
def calc(source, threshold):
    sum=0
    for counter, num in enumerate(source):
    sum = sum + num
    if sum >= threshold:
        return counter
```

It does the job, but when working with large arrays it takes long time to execute, is there a function that does this? or is there any other faster option to achieve the same result?

Comment: are you using numpy? is source a numpy array or something?

Comment: yes, its numpy, sorry for not mentioning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You can do this in a single line using

- `a[a.cumsum() > threshold][0]` for matched **`value`**
- `np.where(a.cumsum() > threshold)[0][0]` for matched **`index`**

as follows.

```py
a = np.array([10,20,30,40])
threshold = 30

# To get the first value that
# matches the condition
matched_value = a[a.cumsum() > threshold][0]
print(f'matched_value: {matched_value}')
# To get the first index that
# matches the condition
matched_index = np.where(a.cumsum() > threshold)[0][0]
print(f'matched_index: {matched_index}')
```

**Output**:

```sh
matched_value: 30
matched_index: 2
```

### Example

Here's another example.

```py
import numpy as np
#a = np.random.randint(0, high=100, size=10)
a = [75, 38, 23, 59,  0, 16, 96, 60, 52, 58]
a = np.array(a)
print(f'array: {a}')
# Cumulative sum
print(f'cumsum: {a.cumsum()}')
# First element in the array where the
# cumulative sum is greater than a given value
threshold = 180
value = a[a.cumsum() > threshold][0]
print(f'Target Cumsum Threshold: {threshold} \n' + f'Value: {value}')
```

**Output**:

```sh
array: [75 38 23 59  0 16 96 60 52 58]
cumsum: [ 75 113 136 195 195 211 307 367 419 477]
Target Cumsum Threshold: 180
Value: 59
```

Comment: This returns the value, not the index, which is what the question asks

Comment: @talonmies Thank you for pointing it out. I will update the solution.

Comment: @Dan Please consider **voting up** the answer, given you accepted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

suppose a is a numpy array [10,20,30,40] and the threshold is 30.
code to return the indices, from which the cumulative sum is greater than or equal to  threshold

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([10,20,30,40])
threshold = 30
a = list(a)
indices_list = [a.index(item) for i,item in enumerate(a) if sum(a[:i+1])>=threshold]
if indices_list !=[]:
     print('Required element is',a[indices_list[0]])
```